# Video captions below video field

Tags: files

I'm expanding my language learning site and need a bit of help if it's possible. 
I am wanting to link to YouTube videos (that's easy). But I would like to have a captions field. As the video plays the captions would appear in the field. I need to do this so that the user can copy and paste the caption and there will be two lines of captioning "Language 1" and "Language 2." I might in the future add a second field below the captions that would give a grammar explanation to the caption being displayed as well.

The only thing I have found while searching around is: https://www.drupal.org/node/1927080 but it puts the captions into the video.

```
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|              VIDEO              |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|           LANGUAGE 1            |
|                                 | <= Changes based on video time
|           LANGUAGE 2            |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|            GRAMMAR?             | <= Changes based on video time
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to find any existing module to do this and would be quite surprised if one existed. You will very likely have to develop your own module.

Here is a brief rundown of how such a module might work:

1. Implement a new field type providing either a form for the user to create the subtitles or upload a subtitle file in one of the many subtitle formats. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2734698?hl=en
2. Parse the input from the form and store it. You'd likely want to store it as JSON or something else that will be easy to work with in JavaScript
3. Write code to pass the data to the browser
4. Use Javascript to update the Language 1 and Language 2 content to match the data in your stored subtitle file. You can use the YouTube API to get the current time of the video https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status

I think it would be a lot easier to just use YouTube to do this but I'm sure you've already thought of that.